# jQuery selector match partial (end)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am attempting to find inputs with the name ending in `type`.  The actual name will be `Ntype` where N is `0-9` i.e. `0type`.

How can I easily select the correct input whose name ends in type?

```
$(this).find("input[name='type']").val()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$=`

```
$(this).find("input[name$='type']").val()
```

---

`$=` ends with
`^=` begins with
`*=` contains

to remember this syntax it may be useful think about regulars expression *line anchors* and *quantifiers*

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$(this).find("input[name$='type']").val();
```

This page might be useful for future reference:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find("input[name$='type']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by

```
$(this).find("input[name$='type']").val()
```